# PHP & RegEx: Get raw data between XML tags, even if whole XML seems to be invalid

Tags: javascript, php, xml, regex, simplexml

This question seems to be asked often before, but I found no working solution for data, that is very long and contains special charcaters like "<" or "{" or...and so on.

I am submitting some huge XML data to PHP on a server, which looks like this:

```
<root><id>1</id><text>Here is a very long text with

line breaks, white-spaces and many very unsual charchaters, e.g. < % & }

the text can be more then 5000 characters long

</text></root>
```

On the server side, I am trying to get the "raw data" between the the text tag. The raw data inside the "text tags", can include anything you can image: white-spaces, line-breaks, weird characters. What I submit is source code and text, formatted by CKEditor and a code syntaxhighlighter.

I read me through this and basically everybody says "use a XML parser", like domDocument don't use RegEx.

First of all I tried several RegEx statements, for example. This is not the only one I tried. When the data conatins brackets and the data is too long, it will fail:

```
//#<text[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</text>#
$regex = "#<".$element_name."[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</".$element_name.">#";

$found = preg_match($regex, $xml, $matches);

if ($found != false) 
{
    $result = $matches[0];
    return $result;
}
```

Second I tried with this, which works if the data inside the tags is not too weird. I think the parser doesn't like brackets "<" and thinks the xml is not valid.

```
 function getTextBetweenTags($tag, $html, $strict=0)
{
    /*** a new dom object ***/
    $dom = new domDocument;

    /*** load the html into the object ***/
    if($strict==0)
    {
        $dom->loadXML($html);
    }
    else
    {
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
    }

    /*** discard white space ***/
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    /*** the tag by its tag name ***/
    $content = $dom->getElementsByTagname($tag);

    /*** the array to return ***/
    //$out = array();
    foreach ($content as $item)
    {
        /*** add node value to the out array ***/
        //$out[] = $item->nodeValue;
        /*** return only the first found element value ***/
        return $item->nodeValue;
    }
    /*** return empty string if nothing found ***/
    return "";
}
```

So my question is:

If I exactly know, there is only one beginning and ending "text"-tag inside the data, what is the best way, to read the raw data with PHP?

If anyone gave me a working regex or a code-snippet, it would be great.

Sorry for my medium english.

**===RESPONSE TO ANSWERS===RESPONSE TO ANSWERS===RESPONSE TO ANSWERS===**

Ok, both answers from BogdanM and Steven do work, but my favourite answer is from BogdanM.

What I did. to get this working:

1. I create my own XML on the client site and I now use CDATA to tell the parser where the data begins and ends
2. On server side I use SimpleXML to parse the data. Using CDATA it has no more problems to parse it. No more matter how "weird" the data is.
3. I eliminated a common "Rookie error" to send big data with HTTP-GET. I now just use HTTP-POST to have not limits

Thank you again for the help.

Comment: I tried your first attempt, it worked for me.

Comment: Instead of regexp, you can use `strpos()` to find the beginning and ending tags, then `substr()` to get the text between them.

Comment: I tried it with the example data you posted at the top of your question. How much huger does it have to get to fail?

Comment: BTW, instead of `[\s\S]`, use `.` and add the `s` modifier to the regexp so that `.` matches newline.

Comment: Like this?: #<text[^>]*>.*?</text>#/s The example data above was just to show how the xml is made.

Comment: Right, except no `/` at the end. The modifier goes right after the end delimiter.

Comment: I tried expanding your sample XML to about 20,000 characters by appending multiple copies of it, it still worked.

Comment: Like this?: #<text[^>]*>.*?</text>#s   ....I will try it.

Comment: I will come back tommorrow with a "fresh head" and will test all the suggestions and give detailed feedback. After coding for more then 10 hours I don't see clear, what I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you generating the XMLs as well? 
Because if you are, you should put your text data between CDATA. Then load your xml with simplexml or some parser of your choice and get the text tag contents.
Make sure you don't have UTF-8 characters orm some such which are not allowed in XML at all: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Char

Otherwise you could do this:

```
preg_match('#<text>(.+?)</text>#is', $xml, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // your data between <text> and </text>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your original regex pattern, is okay and should work fine:

```
#<".$item_name."[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)</".$item_name.">#
```

However, you could alter it to make it more readable/functional etc...

## Possibilities

### Regex 1

```
#<text>(.*)</text>#is
```

Simply capture everything between the `text` tags. Use modifiers `i` to allow `TEXT` and `text` tags and `s` to make `.` match new lines.

### Regex 2

```
#<text.*?>(.*)</text>#is
```

Your original regex implies that you expect to receive extra characters in your opening `text` tag. The `.*?` within the opening tag allows for this - the `?` makes it stop at the first `>`.

### Regex 3

```
#<(text).*?>(.*)</\1>#is
```

As the opening and closing tag name are the same (i.e. `text`) you can place parenthesis around the opening tag to make it a capture group and simply reference in the closing tag with `\1` - as it's the first capture group.

This means that there's one less chance to make a spelling mistake!

### Regex 4

```
#<('.$item_name.').*?>(.*)</\1>#is
```

Making it more dynamic. You can replace the word `text` with a variable (as per your original). Mixing this with the capture groups and referencing as in **Regex 3** you only have to insert the variable once leading to cleaner more readable code.

#### Comparison v Original

```
#<('.$item_name.').*?>(.*)</\1>#is
#<".$item_name."[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)</".$item_name.">#
```

## Working Example

Using **Regex 4** above

```
$string = "
<root><id>1</id><text>Here is a very long text with

line breaks, white-spaces and many very unsual charchaters, e.g. < % & }

the text can be more then 5000 characters long 

</text></root>";

preg_match('#<('.$item_name.').*?>(.*)</\1>#is', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

/**
Output:

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(167) "<text>Here is a very long text with

line breaks, white-spaces and many very unsual charchaters, e.g. < % & }

the text can be more then 5000 characters long 

</text>"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "text"
  [2]=>
  string(154) "Here is a very long text with

line breaks, white-spaces and many very unsual charchaters, e.g. < % & }

the text can be more then 5000 characters long 

"
}

*/
```

**NOTE:** If you are unable to get the above working example to... *work*... then could you perhaps provide (either by editing into your question or linking too) an example case where it would not work?